# CSS Horizontal Navigation menu list alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to design a menu and submenu like [this](http://kardan.edu.af/).

I tried to make enhancements in the menu I already have, but it doesn't start from the beginning of the menu. I tried to edit the CSS but I can't figure out where to fix this issue.

Here is the screenshot of the menu I am trying to fix.

[image]

**The HTML for the menu:**

```
<div style="width:100%; border:1px solid black" align="center">
<ul id="nav-one" class="dropmenu" style="width:1024px; border:1px solid black;"> 
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Home</a> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <a href="#">ABOUT BOST</a> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Your work</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <a href="#item3">Downloadsfdsfsd</a> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Office</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Custom projects</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li>  
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Productsfsdfsdfsd</a> 
                <div class="products" align="left">
                    <ul> 
                        <li><img src="images/236872.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Featured Box</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/242702.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Mod Rewriter</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/242177.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Byte Scrambler</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/226138.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Image Processor</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/216794.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Registry Class</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/211826.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Data Validation</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                        <li><img src="images/203708.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Thumb" border="0" /><h2>Ajax Tables</h2><p><a href="#">More information about this product</a></p></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <div class="small">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Tutorials</a> 
                <div class="tutorials">
                    <ul class="left"> 
                        <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="right"> 
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Actionscript</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <div class="small">View <a href="#">all categories</a> or a <a href="#">list of the best tutorials</a>.</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Links</a> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">My websites</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Cool stuff</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Sitebase</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Login</a> 
                <div class="login">
                    <label for="txtuser">Username: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtuser" id="txtuser" />
                    <label for="txtuser">Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" name="txtpass" id="txtpass" />
                    <button>Login</button>
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul> 
        </div>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
ul, li{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul.dropmenu{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:transparent url(images/navigation.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    display:block;
    height: 35px;
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropmenu li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dropmenu li a{
    height: 22px;
    padding: 9px 30px 0px 15px;
    display: block;
    cursor: point;
    border-right: solid 1px #4a779d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropmenu li span{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background:transparent url(images/arrow_up.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 10px;
}
.dropmenu li  a:hover span{
    background:transparent url(images/arrow_hover.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
.dropmenu li:hover ul, .dropmenu li:hover div{
    display: block;
}
.dropmenu ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/gradient.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
.dropmenu ul li{
    border: 0;
    float: none;
}
.dropmenu ul a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:block;
  color: #0657AD;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: none;
}
a.selected, a:hover{
    color: #0657AD !important;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/gradient.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
a.selected span{
    background:transparent url(images/arrow_hover.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
.dropmenu ul a:hover {
    color:#F67A00 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    background-image: none;
}
.dropmenu div ul{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.dropmenu li div{
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/gradient.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropmenu li div ul{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    position: relative !important;
}
.dropmenu li div a{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropmenu li div div{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
.dropmenu li div div a{
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.dropmenu li div div a:hover{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.left{
    float:left;
    width: 145px;
}
ul.right{
    float:right;
    width: 145px;
}
.small{
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 10px 5px 8px 5px !important;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.products{
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.products ul{
    width: 100%;
}
.products ul li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
.products h2{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 2px 0px 3px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.products p{
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.products img{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.products  ul li a{
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.products  ul li  a:hover{
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none !important;
}

.tutorials{
    width: 300px;
}

.login{
    padding: 15px !important;
    width: 180px;
}
input{
    border:1px solid #4A779D;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 164px;
}
label{
    padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    display:block;
}
button{
    background: #4A779D url(images/navigation.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    color: #FFF;
    border:1px solid #4A779D;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: for a start you can add the following to your css as an example of how to alter the submenus. Ill try offer more tomorrow!

ul>li>ul>li{width:400px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix this two classes that you have:

```
.dropmenu li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and this

```
.products{
    left:0;
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

just substitute it

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
.products{
  width: 960px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  float:left;
}
```